# Functions that converge when repeatedly applied to itself

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence

Suppose a function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with the property

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\; \underbrace{f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f}_{\mathrm{n \;times}}(x) = c = \mathrm{const.}
$$

i.e. it converges in the limit to a finite number when repeatedly applied to itself. Also $\exists\, a, b \in \mathbb{R}, s.t. \; f(a)\neq f(b)$ should hold (i.e. only non-constant functions).

As pointed out in the comments $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ is not a valid example. So I don't have any example function with that property but $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ on the other hand is bound though it doesn't converge.

Now I am interested in the following aspects:

- Can one identify a subset of all functions for which this property is present (for any value of $c$)?
- Do such functions have other specific properties that are perhaps common among all of them (and related to the value of $c$)?
- Do functions exist for which $c = 0$ (perhaps $f(x) = \sin(x)$ but I'm not sure how to approach this)?
- Do functions exist for which $c \neq 0$?

I am particularly interested in the case $c = 0$.

Comment: For the last three points, consider constant functions. Boring examples, but no less true.

Comment: maybe $e^{-|x|}$ for $c=0$? or something along those lines

Comment: But for $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$ the limit is 0 when $x=0$?

Comment: Searching the Internet for "contraction mapping" will turn up quite a lot of examples and reference literature.

Comment: Square root is a good example, but the attractive fixed-point is 1, not 0. 0 is a repulsive fixed-point (physicists would say that 1 is a stable equilibrium and 0 an unstable equilibrium). And function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ has three fixed-points, -1, 0 and 1; 0 is repulsive, and -1 and +1 are attractive. However, you can choose some $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ and have $f(x) = \max(\varepsilon, \sqrt{|x|})$ and now -1 and +1 are the only two fixed-points.

Comment: For a most-simple example, any affine function $f(x) = ax+b$ with $|a| < 1$ will have a unique fixed-point $x_0 = \frac{b}{1-a}$, and this fixed-point's basin of attraction is all of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

The most common tool for dealing with these is the Banach fixed point theorem:

Let $f$ be a function from an interval $I$ to itself, and suppose there is some $k<1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le k|x-y|$. Then there is a unique fixed point $a$ such that $f(a)=a$. Also, for any initial $x_0\in I$, the sequence $x_n=f(x_{n-1})=f^{n}(x_0)$ converges to $a$.
With minor tweaks, that interval $I$ can be replaced by any complete metric space.

So, what does this mean here, with your functions implicitly from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself? We can ensure that Lipschitz condition by bounding the derivative; if $|f'(x)|\le k$ for all $x$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|\le k|x-y|$ as well.

That's what I have to say on your first bullet point.

For your final batch of questions, here's a function for which the iterates converge to any given $c$:
$$f_c(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{c}{2}$$

For the second bullet point - the Banach theorem doesn't have a full converse. We can have that convergence without those conditions, as $\sin$ and $\cos$ demonstrate (Yes, the iterates of $\sin$ converge to zero. Very slowly). There is a partial converse; if the iterates $f^n$ converge to a fixed point $a$ in some neighborhood of $a$ and $f$ is differentiable, then $|f'(a)|\le 1$. We need that, or the iterates will keep getting farther away.

Answer (score 0):

your square root example fails at zero.

This is a simple class of examples, by no means exhaustive:

take any differentiable function  such that there is a constant $\varepsilon > 0$   with
$$ | f'(x) | \leq 1 - \varepsilon    $$
for all $x \in \mathbb R$

Proposition 1: there is at most one fixpoint.

Proposition 2: there is a point with $f(a) < 0$ and a point with $f(b) > 0$

Proposition 3: there is a fixpoint $c$

Proposition 4: the fixpoint is globally attracting

Comment: You can relax the differentiable requirement quite substantially to "Lies between $(1-\varepsilon)(x-c)+c$ and $(1-\varepsilon)(c-x)+c$". No need for differentiability, or even continuity.

Comment: @Arthur understood. If someone appears to be a beginner in a topic, i mostly go for simplicity in an example, rather then generality.